# AWS S3 QuickSight manifest file URIs required?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to load s3 json files into Quicksight and if I do not list every file in the URIs array the loading fails. According to the documentation I only need to use URIprefixes array for loading all files in a given bucket.

I get an error that no URIs were found. What am I missing here ?

```
    {
    "fileLocations": [
      {
       "URIPrefixes": [
        "s3://mybucket/timesheet/"
      ]
    }
    ],
   "globalUploadSettings": {
       "format": "JSON"
       }
    }
```

Separate issue is that if I do specify a list of files they do all load however one element in all of JSON files is an array of "items" and these data are completely missing.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am exactly with the same problem :)

Comment: have you granted permissions to "mybucket"??

Manage QuickSight-> Security & permissions -> Manage -> "Select s3 Buckets"